# How can I get my html5 <nav> to work correctly in IE 9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, nav

Wondering if my script is wrong or if I'm missing something in CSS.  It's working great in everything except my IE 9 browser - version 9.0.8112.16421.  I think it's the box-orient that's messing it up but I thought the html5shiv would help that?

Here is my HTML for head:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>US Fire Registry</title>
<!--update based on html5-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="Fire Registry" />    
<meta content="fire registry volunteer firefighters" />
<link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/favicon.ico"> 
<link href="http://www.usfireregistry.com/css01.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

Html for nav:

     <nav>

        <a href="index.html" id="selected">Home </a>
        <a href="registry.html">Firefighter Registry </a>
        <a href="agency.html">Agency Honors </a>
        <a href="auxilary.html">Auxilary Honors </a>
        <a href="training.html">Training Project </a>
        <a href="showcase.html">Equipment Showcase </a>
        <a href="store.html">Store </a>
      </nav>




And CSS:

nav {
    background-color: #992017;
    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-orient:horizontal;
        -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    /*IE*/
    -ms-box-orient:horizontal;
    width: 975px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 60;
}

nav a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-flex:1.0; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-flex:1.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -ms-box-flex:1.0;
    box-flex:1.0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s linear;
    -o-transition:all .4s linear;
    -moz-transition:all .4s linear;
    transition:all .4s linear;
}
```

Comment: IE9 supports HTML5 elements so that shouldn't be the problem. Nav is semantic and shouldn't really be used for positioning or excessive styling. Wrap it in a div if you need to position it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Shiv" script will allow older versions of IE (7,8) to treat the HTML 5 elements as modern browsers treat them. This script does *not* allow CSS 3 properties to take affect in a browser that doesn't support them.

Using the new `display: box;` value in a browser that doesn't support it (IE 9) is what the problem is. The `-ms` prefixes are for IE 10 not 9 .. I also suggest waiting until the **CSS Flexible Box Layout** module comes closer to the recommended stage - its currently in revision and things may certainly change as it gets closer to completion.